# .htaccess rewrites one url, not the other

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I've got this set of `.htaccess` rewrites set up (Zend Framework default rewrite rules):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

My `DocumentRoot` folder contains only `.htaccess` and `index.php`, nothing else.

The rewrite rules should send all requests to non-existing files through index.php. 
This happens for `/herp/derp/` (wheter a controller exists or not) , but not for `/index/herp/` or any other url starting with `/index/`.

All `/index/*` urls are routed to the 404 page of apache, all other urls do work.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that MultiViews do this. Still not sure why :P